# Build APK and EXE with react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk, exe

I want to create an App using React-Native, I know it's possible to build APK and IPA. But I am wondering if it's possible to build an EXE too for a desktop winwdows app?

If so, is there a hello world example ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8964300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be late...But this answer can be useful.. react-native-windows is the official Microsoft support for react native for UWP.

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows

Comment: Works with Windows 10 only

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible in React Native to build exe for Windows .

Answer (score 2):

While you *may* not be able to develop a desktop Windows app today with React Native, you will be able to very soon.

From the [announcement](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/13/react-native-on-the-universal-windows-platform/) by the Windows Apps Team on April 13, 2016:

> Today, Microsoft and Facebook announced at Facebook’s developer
>   conference, [F8 2016](https://www.fbf8.com/), that we’re adding Universal Windows Platform
>   (UWP) support to React Native. This is provided as an open source,
>   community-supported framework. The new UWP support extends the reach
>   of these native apps to a new market of 270 million active Windows 10
>   devices, and the opportunity to reach beyond mobile devices, to PCs,
>   and even the Xbox One and HoloLens.

From the [announcement](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/articles/ReactNativeWindows.html) by [Jonathan Carter](https://twitter.com/lostintangent) via the CodePush Blog on April 13, 2016:

> We haven’t published the Windows support to NPM yet, but if you want
>   to check it out, you can view the source and/or install the bits from
>   our [Windows
>   branch](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/tree/windows-support),
>   which includes an updated readme with setup instructions.
>   Additionally, if you want to check out a sample app that uses React
>   Native for Windows and CodePush, the beautiful and open-sourced [F8 App](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app)
>   is a great example to play around with. The production version of the
>   app already uses CodePush for iOS and Android, and we implemented a
>   [fork of it](https://github.com/CatalystCode/f8app/tree/CodePushWindows/windows) which includes CodePush support on Windows. Clone the fork,
>   run the setup instructions, and try it out! The above screenshots were
>   taken using it, so feel free to have fun with running the app on the
>   various device emulators.

[Windows React Native Example](https://github.com/CatalystCode/f8app/tree/CodePushWindows/windows)